# How to manage onBackPressed from settings activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am calling `Settings` activity from another activity using the `startActivityForResult` method. When the back button is clicked, it goes back to the screen on my application. But this activity had already been loaded before calling the settings activity, so I want to be able to refresh the activity on back click on the settings activity. How do I do that?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to accompany your verbal explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to implement the `onActivityResult()` method in your first activity. This method will be called any time an activity you've started with `startActivityForResult()` finishes.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == yourRequestCode) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

In the case of the BACK button, the `resultCode` argument will be `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`. This doesn't really change things, but lots of examples will include checking for `resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK` and I just wanted to mention that it's perfectly fine to do things even when the result code is something else.

Comment: It works. Thank you. Although, i did notice something weird. I'm going to explain the entire situation. So, i'm basically checking if a particular setting is on or off on startup of the app. If the setting is on, a dialog(which cannot be cancelled) is displayed. A button on the dialog redirects the user to settings. If the user switches the setting off and comes back to the app, the dialog vanishes(I used what you said for this) I do have another small problem though. The setting is off, the dialog opens, i go to settings, let the setting be on and come back to the app.

Comment: (continued) The dialog is still there as it should be. I go to settings again and this time switch the setting off and come back to the app. This time, the dialog is still there. No idea why. This shouldn't be happening as i check if the setting is on or off every time the user presses back from the settings activity. Please help.

Comment: @Chirag I'd be happy to try to help, but I think you should create a new question. Being able to see code would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // your code...

}
```

In the method implement what has to be needed to be updated.